# boost::condition_variable_any stucks randomly and still in data race

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to use boost::condition_variable_any to prevent race condition as a function is called from multiple threads but randomly the code stucks at 
cond.timed_wait(mutx,boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));

What I understand is even if notify_one function is not raised it should release itself after 500 milliseconds but it gets stuck. Below is the actual code of the function i am using.

```
boost::mutex mtx_;  //Declared in header file

void OnDataEventHandler(FinalPrice _fp)
        {
            if(_fp.BID[0].Price > 5 && _fp.ASK[0].Price > 5 &&  _fp.BID[0].Price < _fp.ASK[0].Price)
{

    ///boost::unique_lock<boost::timed_mutex> lock{mutx};
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock{mutx};
    {

        _IOCData[_fp.Token] = _fp;



        if(BidBuyOrder)
        {


            if(_BNSFMNQ > 0  && SellTradeCounter < Token1MaxReverseRatio && BNSFDIFF !=0)
            {
                dAsksDifference=0;

                for(int iLeg=0; iLeg < IterateCount ; iLeg++)
                {
                    dAsksDifference += GetReverseSpreadValue(iLeg);
                }



                if(BNSFDIFF <= dAsksDifference)
                {

                    SellTradableQty =min(Token1MinReverseRatio,( Token1MaxReverseRatio - SellTradeCounter ));
        OrderPlaced = true;
                }
            }


            if( _BFSNMNQ > 0 && BuyTradeCounter < Token1MaxCreateRatio && BFSNDIFF!=0)
            {

                dBidsDifference=0;

                for(int iLeg=0; iLeg < IterateCount ; iLeg++)
                {
                    dBidsDifference += GetCreateSpreadValue(iLeg);
                }


                if(BFSNDIFF <= dBidsDifference)
                {

                    BuyTradableQty =  min ( Token1MinCreateRatio, ( Token1MaxCreateRatio - BuyTradeCounter));
                    OrderPlaced = true;
                }
            }
        }




        if(OrderPlaced)
        {

            cout << " Locked state waiting to release PFNumber "<< PFNumber <<endl;
           // cond.wait(mutx);

             // Code stucks here randomly at wait

            cond.timed_wait(mutx,boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
            cout << " Locked state released PFNumber "<<  PFNumber <<endl;
             OrderPlaced = false;
        }
    }


   // boost::timed_mutex *m = lock.release();
   // m->unlock();


 }
```

}

Please guide.

Edit :

OnDataEventHandler defined above is raised from a threadA using boost::event and conditional notify events are raised from a threadB once the response arrives over TCP socket. Many a times response recieved are either delayed due to some calculations or any circumstances hence i added timed release to the mutex but it stucks randomly. The exact stuck situation can't be defined here but the last message i see in the log is  "Locked state waiting to release PFNumber" which is just above the locking.

Even after the locking, may be due to events on thread two variables which are there to control the count to the limit demanded by user named "BuyTradeCounter " and "SellTradeCounter " ( Can be found as a comparision in the first code OnDataEventHandler goes beyond the count, which i think can only happen if its in data race,but i have controlled it with condition variable.

check 1:  "SellTradeCounter < Token1MaxReverseRatio"

check 2:  "BuyTradeCounter < Token1MaxCreateRatio"

These two variables are updated from threadB and then the lock is released. 
The code for event on threadB is below:

```
   void TRADE_CONFIRMATION_TR (MS_TRADE_CONFIRM_TR obj_Trade)
  {

        int Qty = htonl(obj_Trade.FillQuantity)/75;

        if(_BS==BUY)
        {
            BuyTradeCounter= BuyTradeCounter + Qty;
        }
        else if(_BS==SELL)
        {

            SellTradeCounter = SellTradeCounter + Qty;
        }

     cout << "Releasing Locked state from Trade PF "<< PFNumber <<endl;
    cond.notify_one();
    cout << "Released Locked state from Trade PF "<< PFNumber <<endl;
 }
```

Please guide.

Comment: Can you put together a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.  The code, as posted, appears to be fine regarding the mutex and condition variable.

Comment: @G.M. I have updated the code with detailed issue . Please guide .